# How to rotate the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to rotate camera of my player, but the code below are don't work. I use it it my save/load game functionality

```
public void ButtonSave()
 {
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("transform position x" + currentActiveSlot, playerTransform.position.x);
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("transform position y" + currentActiveSlot, playerTransform.position.y);
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("transform position z" + currentActiveSlot, playerTransform.position.z);

     // Save all 4 values for the quaternion
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("transform rotation x" + currentActiveSlot, playerTransform.rotation.x);
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("transform rotation y" + currentActiveSlot, playerTransform.rotation.y);
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("transform rotation z" + currentActiveSlot, playerTransform.rotation.z);
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("transform rotation w" + currentActiveSlot, playerTransform.rotation.w);

     PlayerPrefs.Save();
 }
 public void ButtonLoad() // call via canvas UI load button
 {
     // this work
     playerTransform.position = new Vector3(
             PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform position x" + currentActiveSlot),
             PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform position y" + currentActiveSlot),
             PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform position z" + currentActiveSlot));

     // this don't work
     Quaternion savedRotation = new Quaternion(
             PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform rotation x" + currentActiveSlot),
             PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform rotation y" + currentActiveSlot),
             PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform rotation z" + currentActiveSlot),
             PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("transform rotation w" + currentActiveSlot));
     playerTransform.rotation = savedRotation;    
 }
```

Tried combinations below, but they don't work too

```
playerTransform.Rotate(new Vector3(1, 2, 3));
playerTransform.Rotate(1, 2, 3);
playerTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
```

And after starting the simulation I can't rotate it by hands

[image]

**Edit1**

[image]

Comment: If you can't "rotate by hands"', you surely have an Update function setting the rotation, and overriding what you try to set from the editor.

Comment: I think you right, but I can't find this place =(

Comment: You will have to proceed step by step : Disable the various scripts on your character, and then, when you know which one set the rotation, dig into the code to find something like `transform.rotation = ....`

Comment: @Hellium I disabled all objects on the scene and I only can change transform.rotation, when disable player's first person conrtoller like in the Edit1. When I enable it again, all rotation data take it's default values

Comment: If the rotation is set by the `First Person Controller` script, find the line setting the rotation in the source code (something like `transform.rotation =` or `transform.Rotate`. You will have to modify the source code of the script so as to take into account the piece of code you have written in your question. I won't be able to help you any further.

Comment: @Hellium Thanks with that)